# Jquery Dynamic button creation and registeration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have create a page that gets the users information based on the username. This works fine. After getting the information the user has to provide some answer. At this point i have used jquery to create another button to submit this information. The button is being created however the page that is being called on the dynamically created button doesnt work. I have checked some solutions available online but in vain.

**script4.js**

```
    jQuery(function($) {
    var val_holder;

    $("form input[name='register1']").click(function() { // triggred click 
        $(anew_val).hide();
        var username = jQuery.trim($("form input[name='username']").val()); // usernamefield
        if(username == "") { // check if username is blank
            $("span.username_val").html("This field is empty.");
            val_holder = 1;
        }

        if(val_holder == 1) {
            return false;
        }  

        var datastring = '&username='+ username; //sends data to php page

        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST", // type
                 url: "credentialcheck.php", // request file the 'check_email.php'
                 data: datastring, // post the data
                 success: function(q1) { // get the response
                 if(q1 != "") { // if the response is 1
                    $("span.username_val").html("");
                    $(".squestion").html(q1);
                    $(".squestion1").html("Question");
                    $(".aquestion").html("<input type='text' id='sans1' name='sans1'> </input>");
                    $(".aquestion1").html("Answer");
                    //$(".anew").html("<input type='button' name='nsign1' value='Sign In' onClick='at()'></input>");
                   //  $(".anew").html("<input name='register' type='button' value='Sign In' > </input>");
                      //$(anew_val).show();   


                    $(".anew").html("<input name='register' id= 'register' class='register' type='button' value='Sign In'>"); 

                    jQuery('#' + 'register').button().click(function() {

            alert('Dynamically added button was clicked.');

        });


                    $(signup).hide();


                 } 
                else 
                { // else blank response

                          $("span.username_val").html("<img src='images/invalid.png'> You aren't registred.");
                           $(".squestion").html("");
                           $(".lsquestion").html(" ");
                            $(".aquestion").html(" ");
                        $(".laquestion").html("");
                        }
                    } // end success
        }); // ajax end
        /************** end: email exist function and etc. **************/
    }); // click end

});
```

**script6.js**

```
    jQuery(function($) {
      $(document).on("click", ".register", function(){
            alert("1");
       }); // click end
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, If you want to get a perfect answer for your question, you should post some code attempts of you. And make sure you are being clear in your point.

Comment: Script 4 create's the button. Script 6 is called when the created butoon is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the .button() and see like:

```
jQuery('#' + 'register').on("click",function() {

    alert('Dynamically added button was clicked.');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have attached click event to the button using following syntax

```
$(document).ready
    (
        function()
        {
            $('.MyButtonClass').click
                (
                function ()
                {
                    alert('aa');
                });
        }
    );
```

use the new on event as follows

```
$(document).ready
    (
        function()
        {
            $('#ContainerWhichContainButton').on('click', '.MyButtonClass', function ()
            {
                alert('aa');
            });           
        }
    );
```

Second way is attach click event after the button is created
example

```
          $('#ss').append($('<input>').attr('type', 'button').val('aaaa').addClass('MyButtonClass'));
          $('.MyButtonClass').click
                (
                function ()
                {
                    alert('aa');
                });
```

Hope it helped